# How do I measure screen width and screen depth?

Tags: pixels

I would like to know whether you might have a quick program which measures screen width and screen height.  For example,  starting off reading left to right (or right to left), I would like to know the proportion of the screen being used in terms of:
number of pixels used for width / total width of pixels

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What do you mean by `the proportion of the screen being used`? Used by what ?

Comment: Are you asking what the resolution is? If so, you can find this out in Control Panel -> Display -> Adjust Resolution.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing in some gui framework there are always hardcoded methods to obtain native width and height of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to measure the width / heights of applications/graphics etc on screen, search Google for `on screen ruler` such as [Jruler](http://www.spadixbd.com/freetools/jruler.htm) (free). This way, if you have several windows open, you can measure the length/height of each application. Or, on a website, you could measure how wide the left menu is compared to the right menu.